# JavaScript isnan issue

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a calculator which will check if there is letters added, and if so give a alert message, it semi works. I can type -2, +2 etc. etc. but I can't type 2+2,2-2 etc. then the alert pops, is there anyway to exclude like number + number from isnan?

```
 <script>
function checkNum(){
    var n = document.kalk.disp.value;
    if(isNaN(n) == true){
       alert("Endast siffror!");
    }else{
  kalk.disp.value=eval("kalk.disp.value");
    }
}
</script>

  <form name="kalk">
 <input type="text" name="disp" >
 <br>
 <input type="button" value="7" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='7'">
 <input type="button" value="8" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='8'">
 <input type="button" value="9" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='9'">
 <input type="button" value="*" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='*'">
 <br>
 <input type="button" value="4" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='4'">
 <input type="button" value="5" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='5'">
 <input type="button" value="6" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='6'">
 <input type="button" value="-" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='-'">
  <br>
 <input type="button" value="1" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='1'">
 <input type="button" value="2" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='2'">
 <input type="button" value="3" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='3'">
 <input type="button" value="+" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='+'">
 <br>
 <input type="button" value="C" OnClick="kalk.disp.value=''">
 <input type="button" value="0" OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='0'">
 <input type="button" value="." OnClick="kalk.disp.value+='.'">
 <input type="button" value="=" OnClick="checkNum()" >
 </form>
```

ok tried with this, but can't get it working right, it posts the error when I add letters but it doesn't do the eval part

```
<script>
 function checkNum(){
var x = document.kalk.disp.value;
var regex=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
if (x.match(regex))
{
    alert("Must input numbers");
    return false;
   }else{
  kalk.disp.value=eval("kalk.disp.value");
}
}
 </script>
```

Comment: you could just delete all of the odd characters in the string and then eval it.

Comment: If you are going to base your "calculator" on `eval`, then just `try/catch` exceptions.

Comment: Maybe you should just not try to use `eval` for this. Maybe you should create a PEMDAS interpreter yourself.

Comment: *"is ther anyway to exclude like number + number from isnan"* `isNaN` simply checks whether the input can be converted to a number. You cannot influence how `isNaN` is doing that, but you can prepare the input to your liking.

Comment: im kinda blue on javascript. This is the first thing im trying to create so please explain as good as u can haha

Comment: @FelixKling explain more please :)

Comment: He means `isNaN` will check if not a number or not, and `+` or `-` are not numbers since they are not from the `0-9` numeric system

Comment: I'm saying you cannot change how `isNaN` works but you can change what you pass to it.

Comment: either what @FelixKling just said or use regex

Comment: @Mi-Creativity i could try regex i guess, since felix solutions seems abit to complicated for me

Comment: @Mi-Creativity can u tell what part in the new script that is wrong?

Comment: Put the regex inside the match like this `if (x.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/))` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVzZwr

Comment: Why not simply have the regex check for legal characters? `/^[-0-9+*/]+$/` Always much easier than listing every possible illegal character.

Comment: @Mi-Creativity thanks but it still doesnt work for me :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 function checkNum(){
  var x = document.kalk.disp.value;
  var regex=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (x.match(regex))
      {
  alert("Must input numbers");
  return false;
    } else {
    kalk.disp.value=eval(x);
   }
  }
```

thanks!

Comment: Nope this is wrong, you only excluding `a-zA-Z`, what if the user entered this `2+@` ? your alert won't work, same thing for `9-$`, your javascript will scream *`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected...`* and your alert won't work, this is WRONG, you need to exclude these **`~ @ # $ % ^ & = } { [ ] ? ! > < " ' | \ /`** or it will **FAIL**, if other users come and take this as an answer this is misleading!

Answer (score 2):

do it like this: [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/pjmRpL?editors=101)

**JS:**

```
 function checkNum() {
   var x = document.kalk.disp.value;
   if (x.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/)) {
     //console.log('match');
     alert("Must input numbers");
   } else {
     //console.log('NO Match');
     kalk.disp.value = eval(x);
   }
 }
```

---

While the above regex works well to check letters only, the problem is that the input might not be alphabetic but still unwanted, if the user entered characters like `&` , `#` , `@` , `~`, `{` , `}` the `alert` message should appear, adding all these characters to the regex wouldn't look good and it is easy to make mistake, instead to make life easier we check if the input is numbers and `+` , `-` , `*` signs as well as the dot `.` and the brackets `(` , `)` we need to escape these characters and execute the code, other than that we show the alarm, so replace the above js code with this:

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/vNwgzG?editors=101)

**JS:**

```
function checkNum() {
   var x = document.kalk.disp.value;
   if (x.match('^[\-\*-\+\.\(\)0-9]+$')) {
       //console.log('NO Match');
       kalk.disp.value = eval(x);
   } else {
       //console.log('match');
       alert("Must input numbers");
   }
 }
```

Comment: but remember that you still need to check on other characters which should not be accepted even though they're not `a-z`, characters like : `{` , `}`, `[`, `]` , `!` , `@` ..etc.. in your regex rule

Comment: Everything is set now!

Answer (score 0):

You got the `else` added too early

```
 function checkNum(){
   var x = document.kalk.disp.value;
   var regex=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
   if (x.match(regex))
   {
      alert("Must input numbers");
      return false;
   } else {
     kalk.disp.value=eval(x);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesnt want to calculate the numbers :(

Comment: Arghh...not seen: `kalk.disp.value` in `eval` is a string, that's wrong must be either `x` or `document.kalk.disp.value`